# org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_service")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public abstract class Compensation<C extends Compensation> extends AutoIdBasedEntity {
    //properties, setters and getters, equals and hashcode overrides.
}
```

The rest inherit from it (one of them for example):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_service_relocation")
public class RelocationCompensation extends Compensation<RelocationCompensation> {
    //properties, setters and getters, equals and hashcode overrides
}
```

A parent entity that contains a collection of `Compensations`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_case")
@EntityListeners({CompensationCaseNumberListener.class})
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class CompensationCase extends AutoIdBasedEntity {

    @Valid
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "compensationCase", orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "conceptType")
    private Map<ConceptType, Compensation> compensationServices = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Last but not least, I have a the main entity `CompensationFile` which has a collection of `CompensationCase` entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_file")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class CompensationFile extends AutoIdBasedEntity {

    @Valid
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "compensationFile", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<CompensationCase> compensationCases;
}
```

It's strange because this used to work and suddenly it started working up. For some reason it only happens when updating and existing `CompensationCase` and adding a new `Compensation`. For example, if I am persisting an entirely new main `CompensationCase`, it works without a hitch. I use the `JpaRepository` method save on the main entity `CompensationFile` to persist the entire thing as shown below (and where it is throwing the exception):

CompensationFileFormService:

```
@Service
public class CompensationFileFormService {
    @Autowired
    private CompensationFileRepository compensationFileRepository;

    @Autowired
    private CompensationFileFormConverter compensationFileFormConverter;

    @Autowired
    private CompensationCaseService compensationCaseService;        

    public CompensationFileForm saveCompensationFile(CompensationFileForm compensationFileForm) throws TaskNotFoundException, InvalidServiceTypeException, CompensationFileNotFoundException, CompensationCaseNotFoundException {

        CompensationFile compensationFile = compensationFileFormConverter.convertToCompensationFile(compensationFileForm);

        //EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
        CompensationFile newCompensationFile = compensationFileRepository.save(compensationFile);

        if (!newCompensationFile.getCompensationCases().isEmpty()) {
            for (CompensationCase compensationCase : newCompensationFile.getCompensationCases()) {
                compensationCaseTaskService.save(compensationCase, compensationCase.getAssignedPersonnel());
            }
        }

        return createCompensationFileForm(newCompensationFile.getId(), newCompensationFile.getControlId(), compensationFileForm.getSelectedCompensationCase().getId());
    }
}
```

CompensationFileRepository:

```
public interface CompensationFileRepository extends JpaRepository<CompensationFile, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CompensationFile> { 
}
```

Exception thrown:

```
26-Jul-2015 21:45:27.061 SEVERE [http-nio-9090-exec-11] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/nimchip] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutionException: Exception thrown executing [AnnotatedAction@1b7ee93d targetAction = [EvaluateAction@2902b1e5 expression = compensationFileFormService.saveCompensationFile(compensationFileForm), resultExpression = flowScope.compensationFileForm], attributes = map[[empty]]] in state 'save' of flow 'compensation/file/compensation-file' -- action execution attributes were 'map[[empty]]'] with root cause
 org.hibernate.InstantiationException: Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface: sijc.davt.compensation.model.concepts.Compensation
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4440)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:285)
    at org.hibernate.type.MapType.replaceElements(MapType.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:570)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:372)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:896)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$6.cascade(CascadingAction.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:409)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.cascadeOnMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:439)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:308)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:888)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:892)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:344)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy550.merge(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:291)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy550.merge(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:392)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:405)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:390)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:267)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:111)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy677.save(Unknown Source)
    at test.nimchip.davt.compensation.ui.service.CompensationFileFormService.saveCompensationFile(CompensationFileFormService.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.support.ReflectiveMethodExecutor.execute(ReflectiveMethodExecutor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.getValueInternal(MethodReference.java:129)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference.access$000(MethodReference.java:49)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.MethodReference$MethodValueRef.getValue(MethodReference.java:342)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:88)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getTypedValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:131)
    at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:299)
    at org.springframework.binding.expression.spel.SpringELExpression.getValue(SpringELExpression.java:84)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:75)
    at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
    at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ActionState.doEnter(ActionState.java:101)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.State.enter(State.java:194)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:228)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:395)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:116)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:547)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:390)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:231)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:195)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:537)
    at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:259)
    at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
    at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:228)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at test.nimchip.filter.LocaleConfigurerFilter.doFilterInternal(LocaleConfigurerFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help at all will be appreciated.

Comment: What is `compensationFileRepository` and where is it's `save(....)` method declared?Also show code where you are creating `compensationFile` thats passed to this method.

Comment: Added. Let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: I can think of two possible root causes : 1. Has the `Compensation` recently changed from being concrete class to abstract? If yes then there could be data in table for Compensation concrete type. 2. Please check if any of the Compensation sub-class was removed from hierarchy or deleted. If the table contains records for deleted entity type then it can cause the same issue.

Comment: No, it has always been abstract. However, the Compensation sub-class changed to include new properties which should be nullable. I'll take a look at these properties..

Comment: Firstly where is the implementation of `CompensationFileRepository` that `@Autowired private CompensationFileRepository compensationFileRepository;` is supposed to inject. I do not need full java code but show the name of class implementing this and then in your spring config paste where it is configured.You realize it is an interface not class. Secondly if the method is only saving you donot need to do `CompensationFile newCompensationFile = compensationFileRepository.save(compensationFile)` you can just use `compensationFile`.

Comment: It's there after the CompensationFileFormService: here it is again for visibility: `public interface CompensationFileRepository extends JpaRepository<CompensationFile, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<CompensationFile> { 
}`

Comment: It is an interface `public interface CompensationFileRepositor` . See word `interface` after word `public`. You need it's implementation via this autowired injection. implementation  whill be a `class`. My guess is that you don't have that.Thats the reason for this error.

Comment: Nope, sorry that's not it. Read up on `JpaRepository`  here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

Comment: @SukenShah checked new properties and recreated the tables, and its still happening.

Comment: @Nimchip I still believe its data corruption issue. Can you please run database queries to find if there is any row in `Compensation` table that doesn't have its corresponding sub-class table row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out some of the entities that inherited from `Compensation` had properties with `ManyToOne` relations and they were missing cascade annotations. Because they were more than one property, I received no `TransientPropertyValueException` and instead it tried to load the parent `Compensation` entity which was the closest thing that it could associate the entity to without those fields that weren't being cascaded. Which means that this whole problem was due to missing cascade annotations.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_service_relocation")
public class RelocationCompensation extends Compensation<RelocationCompensation> {

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_relocationCompensation_phone")
    private Phone phone = new Phone();

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_relocationCompensation_address")
    private Address address = new Address();

    //rest of properties, setters and getters, equals and hashcode overrides
}
```

Changed to:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "davt_compensation_service_relocation")
public class RelocationCompensation extends Compensation<RelocationCompensation> {

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_relocationCompensation_phone")
    private Phone phone = new Phone();

    @Valid
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    @ForeignKey(name = "FK_relocationCompensation_address")
    private Address address = new Address();

    //rest of properties, setters and getters, equals and hashcode overrides
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For others that the above solutions might not work, give this a thought and a try afterwards: 
When you have you child entities inherit parent entity you will not be able to instantiate the Parent itself but you should instantiate the child that has the parents properties - 
For example i had Parent abstract class Profile and i had a child class StudentProfile that extended it. I tried instantiating a list of profiles and it threw the exception(I had data in the profile table in the database but i forgot to add data to the StudentProfile table(and connect them through the for foreign key column - in my case id)
My solution was to add the corresponding data to the StudentProfile table and then i was able to get rid of the exception. 
Hope this helps!!

Comment: I had another problem where the database had values belonging to all child classes, but the application had excluded one of the child classes ORM file which had one of the child entities during an older refactor. We had one base table, 6 derived tables in DB, and one base class only 5 included derived Java classes

I was able to debug this by first using the FROM Clause (which did the giant outer joins with 5 tables in java) from the hibernate/HQL  log and compare that with a really ugly UNION sql query on all the child tables in plain SQL and compare. Diff helped point to fix

Comment: **TL;DR:** Make sure there is data in one of the inheriting class' tables. If there is only data in the shared superclass table, you will get this exception.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is the only question that comes up you google search this error, I wanted to share another potential solution. I had an issue when my abstract class used Single Table inheritance and gave the 'Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface' exception when I tried to read my pre-loaded data.

My persistence.xml contained the abstract class, but it did not include the classes that extend the abstract class. Since the code to read the classes are not directly referenced they do not throw a invalid entity class exception. When it tried to instantiate the class based on the DiscriminatorColumn value it threw this error. Adding the implementation class to persistence.xml fixed this issue.

Answer (score 2):

My fault was, that I forgot to mark the inherited Entity as such (with @Entity) and so Hibernate had no concrete class to load the data

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using dbRider to setup H2 with test data and forgot to add some yml files with data, which class that was failing to be initialized depended on.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same issue - I was trying to create an instance of the abstract class rather than the concrete subclass

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31868991)

Answer (score -1):

*In my case (not OP's case)::*

I solved it by using `Bounded Type Parameters` -- `<? extends YourAbstractClass>`.

eg::

```java
          String queryStr = "select nn from NodeEvent nn";

//        TypedQuery<NodeEvent> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, NodeEvent.class);
//        List<NodeEvent> resultList = query.getResultList();
          // >> changed to // (NodeEvent is the abstract class where other classes inherit from)
          TypedQuery<? extends NodeEvent> query = em.createQuery(queryStr, NodeEvent.class);
          List<? extends NodeEvent> resultList = query.getResultList();
```